# Store angular components in database

Tags: database, angular, frameworks, frontend, angular-components

I'm looking into the possibility to store components in a database and add them to the Angular application. I see the hinder to add components from a database at runtime with the AOT compiler. My other thought is to store HTML (with usage of ng modules like *ngIf etc.) and CSS for the component in the database and assign it to the component template and styles by fetching the data in the ngInit() function. The main goal is to be able to alter the HTML/CSS from the database.

Does anyone have any thought, experience or tips on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Storing HTML in a database and loading that into a component at runtime, as you suggest, is entirely possible.

On the Angular side, it's as simple as:

```
<div [innerHtml]="queryResult()">
  whatever is in here will be replaced when queryResult returns
</div>
```

In the contexts of headless CMSs specifically this is not at all uncommon. Say you want a user to generate content but want angular to do the page layout. Then the user will generate (rich) content through the CMS, which stores (a modified version of it) as a blob in your database, and creates a back-end endpoint for your front-end to access it. Angular in turn will request that content on component load (through a content.service for example) and take care of the actual view. Angular handles proper sanitization of the HTML string when you use the [innerHtml] property as shown, so it shouldn't be a security concern.

I don't know your use case, but I wouldn't suggest directly storing HTML in the database. I'd strongly suggest using a headless CMS to handle that for you, but it really depends on your stack and use case.

Comment: Thank you. So it's possible but is it good use of a the framework? I'm unsure about this because it feels pretty hack-ish? What are you thoughts?

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect your question. I hope it helps / gives you a starting point going further.

Comment: I've just commented on a similar issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160533/how-to-retrieve-and-submit-a-form-in-angular-6-that-has-been-generated-by-a-djan/54160790#54160790. You'll have the same problem as the author if you store the components in your database and hook them up via [innerHTML]. What you see in your Angular *.html files are not really plain html files. They get transformed to some other form during compilation. The solution is to use Angular Elements and store the resulting .js in the database if you really need to put it in some database

Comment: Your point about angular html being transformed in the building process is entirely correct. Interesting idea to store the component after it has been through the build process. But I really wouldn't want to store entire components in a database like that anyway. If it's *content* then innerHtml is the way to go. I'm working with a client on a project with Django REST API and Wagtail CMS that has exactly that approach for storing content and feeding it to Angular.

Comment: @d.Veen I think the discussion here revolves around content (data). While I see the author also asked about CSS. I assume the use case has to do with changing the look and feel of a web page without doing a redeployment. Am I correct in thinking storing styling information in a CMS (or database) would not be recommended and looked at as bad practice working with Angular (or any front-end framework for that matter)?