# How to retrieve and submit a form in Angular 6 that has been generated by a Django template

Tags: django, angular, forms, http

I have an Angular 6 app and am trying to display and submit a form that is generated from Django. I retrieve the form and display it using innerHtml. It shows up fine but when I click on the Submit button it doesn't call the function that I have attached to it. If I copy and paste the generated html then the submit button works fine (although I get a 403 response I think because of copying and pasting the CSRF token). Here is the code for my Angular component and template files and also the Django template:

login.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="!loggedIn; else successMessage" [innerHTML]="loginForm"></div>

<ng-template #successMessage>
  Logged in
</ng-template>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() loggedIn: boolean;
  id_username: string;
  id_password: string;

  loginForm: SafeHtml;

  constructor(private router: Router, private httpClient: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLoginForm();
  }

  getLoginForm() {
    this.httpClient.get('https://myserver/account/login/', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(res => {
      this.loginForm = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(res);
      console.log(this.loginForm);
    });
  }

  login() {
    console.log("Logging in user");
    var response = this.httpClient.post('https://myserver.com/account/login/', {
      id_username: this.id_username,
      id_password: this.id_password
    }).subscribe(res => {
      this.loggedIn = true;
    });
  }
}
```

form.html Django template

```
{% extends "share/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div>
{% if form %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <font color="red">{{ form.errors }}</font>
    {% endif %}
    <form #bdmForm="ngForm">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ field.label_tag }}
                {{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="login()">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py (To include the fields)
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from **future** import unicode_literals
    from django import forms

```
class Login(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'[(ngModel)]': 'id_username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'[(ngModel)]': 'id_password'}))
```

I have also tried including the login() function using `(ngSubmit)="login()"` in the form tag but that isn't working either.

I am relatively new to Angular and someone else is working on the Django side. I'm not sure if I just need to make a small change or if our whole approach is wrong but any input would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to change the button to `<input type="submit" .... >` and then hook up with `(submit)` on the element you bound with `[innerHtml]` So basically I'd utilize event bubbling.

But to be honest it's bad practice and you shouldn't receive html from your server in your Angular Component. Shortly speaking, you should design your form in Angular and send a POST HTTP Request and react to the response accordingly in your Angular Component.

If it's not possible I think the way to hook up to stuff in your innerHtml is via event bubbling or in runtime via referencing it through document.getElementBySomething and assigning callbacks to events.

Both of the ways feel kind of hacky

Comment: I tried changing the button as you suggested and adding the function to the div instead as follows: `<div *ngIf="!loggedIn; else successMessage" [innerHTML]="loginForm" (submit)="login()"></div>` (I hope that I understood what you meant). When I do this though and press the button it seems to do a GET request with the form inputs as parameters in the address bar and it doesn't hit the login() function at all. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'll also look into setting up the forms on the Angular side instead and talk to the other people on the project about the impacts that will have on the backend. At the moment it's just a demo so hacks are ok but we'll try to use best practices for the final product.

Comment: Here you go :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yqapd5. That's an example on how to use event bubbling from the embedded html

Comment: Thanks, that's calling the function now. However, it's reloading the whole app then so I lose all context. Is there something with the HTTP POST that would cause everything to reload?

Comment: I think that I needed to stop the event after handling it with the function. I've added `(submit)="login($event); false"` to the div and `$event.stopPropagation();` to the function and it's almost working now (just CSRF issues to work out). Hopefully it will work for now until we can do things properly. Thanks for your help!